# Are there more than 1 maha mantra? If so, tell me more about them

Tags: scripture, mantras

Because I had read there are 7 crore Maha-Mantras in the Hindu scriptures

Is it true?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. search mahavakyas on this forum. There are 4 mahavakyas.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

An excerpt from the Devi-Bhagavata-Purana says so-

While describing the glories of Manidvipa, the abode of the great goddess, Vyasa says -

> [Chapter 12](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57415.html), Book 12, Devi Bhagavata Purana
>
> या यास्तु देवतास्तत्र प्रतिब्रह्माण्डवर्तिनाम् ॥ ५२ ॥  समष्टयः
> स्थितास्तास्तु सेवन्ते जगदीश्वरीम् ।  **सप्तकोटिमहामन्त्रा मूर्तिमन्त
> उपासते** ॥ ५३ ॥  महाविद्याश्च सकलाः साम्यावस्थात्मिकां शिवाम् ।
> कारणब्रह्मरूपां तां मायाशबलविग्रहाम् ॥ ५४ ॥  इत्थं राजन् मया प्रोक्तं
> मणिद्वीपं महत्तरम् ।
>
> > The Devas that are in every Brahmāṇḍa all live here and worship Śrī
> > Devī. **The seven Koṭi Mahā Mantras and Mahā Vidyās here assume forms
> > and worship the Mahā Māyā Śrī Bhagavatī**, Who is of the nature of
> > Brahma. O King! Thus I have described to you all about this Maṇidvīpa.
>
> English Translation by Swami Vijnananda

Although, Koṭi is sometimes interpreted as meaning "type/kind", however, the Gita Press Gorakhpur in their [Hindi translation](https://archive.org/details/DeviBhagavataWithHindiTranslationVolume2GitaPress/page/n857/mode/2up?view=theater) of the Sanskrit text translates Koṭi as Crores.

**Thus, as per the Devi Bhagavatam, there are indeed 7 crore different Mahā Mantras.**